# Getting always 0 rows when using @@ROWCOUNT before IF EXISTS statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting always 0 when using `@@ROWCOUNT` after IF EXISTS, **why**?

Here is my code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM MyTable) --Returns one row.
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; --Returns always 0
```

I know that the statement doesn't logical right now, because I expect it to print always 1, so I can also `SELECT 1`, but it is just for demonstration of the problem. The problem it doesn't print 1, it always prints 0.

Comment: The last *statement* that executed is the `IF`. It returned 0 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Provider.Site
  SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; --Returns 1

IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Provider.Site) --Returns one row.
    SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; --Returns always 0
```

Here first `@@ROWCOUNT` return 1 and second returns 0.

Since EXISTS returns only `true` or `false`  and there is no rows affected since it doesn't select any records. It checks the existence only.

Since  `@@ROWCOUNT returns the number of rows affected by the last statement` second case that willl be 0

Answer (score 2):

@@ROWCOUNT by default has 0.
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT; --Returns always 0

SELECT within IF LOOP will change the @@ROWCOUNT to 1.
But after that IF EXISTS condition will change the @@ROWCOUNT to 0 again, and that is the reason you are getting 0 always. Scope of SELECT wont exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get row count for table is not empty, you can query like

```
DECLARE @RC INT;
SELECT @RC = COUNT(*) FROM table
IF(@RC > 0)
    PRINT @RC
```